# How to get intellisense in VSCode from node_modules in unusual place?

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, tsconfig

How can I make VSCode find type declarations for a module installed in a different place?

```
/
└── Users
    └── me
        ├── foo
        |   └── node_modules
        |       └── some-module
        ├── bar
        |   └── file.ts
        └── tsconfig.json
```

```
// bar/file.ts
import {} from 'some-module'
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Cannot find module 'some-module' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I tried the `paths` option from `tsconfig.json` but it didn't work since it tried to find a file called `some-module.ts` inside `foo/node_modules` (it seems it does not know how to interpret `package.json` files in this case)

I tried the `rootDirs` option from `tsconfig.json` but it was ignored since apparently it is only used to attempt to resolve relative imports (while `some-module` is not relative).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Node module resolution won't find this `node_modules` folder, so the error is pretty much correct. Are you sure you _actually can_ use `some-module`? Have you tweaked the module resolution algorithm?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Yes because the build step will copy all these files into a new folder structure that matches a complete working project.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) compiler option:

```json
// /Users/me/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./foo/node_modules",
      // maybe other locations
    ],
  },
}
```

Note, that the default value of `typeRoots` is replaced, rather than extended. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30855) for details.

Comment: Any idea how to do it for javascript?

Comment: There might be a hack, but if you really need this you should seriously consider whether the project’s file structure is correct. The Node’s module resolution algorithm works for [99.9(9)%](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) of cases

Comment: As I mentioned, it is for serverless project where I deploy dependencies as a separate layers.

Comment: I don't see it mentioned anywhere, sorry. I think your issue deserves a separate question, the answer might be very different

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake, I already did another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081632/javascript-intellisense-with-node-modules-in-different-folder