# javascript intellisense with node_modules in different folder

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, lambda, intellisense

I'm having the issue to configure vscode intellisense for the lambda script with layers.

I have the following folder structure:

```
./
  dependencies/
    nodejs/
      package.json
      node_modules/
      libs/
  src/
    index.js
    ...
```

I abled to configure `eslint` to properly detect the `node_modules` folder with this configuration:

**`.eslintrc.cjs`**

```js
...
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        moduleDirectory: ['./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules'],
      },
    },
  },
...
```

But I can't make vscode intellisense to work.
I tried:

**`.vscode/settings.json`**

```json
{
  "javascript.autoImport.searchPaths": [
    "./src",
    "./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules",
    "../dependencies/nodejs/node_modules"
  ]
}
```

But as I understand it is for auto-import.

Comment: side commentary: from the NodeJS perspective, that's a pretty weird way of doing things, given [the way Node module resolution works](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#all-together). Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: what is `"javascript.autoImport.searchPaths"`? I get "Unknown Configuration Setting". What version of VS Code is this? Is that coming from an extension?

Comment: Why not try using the [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) tsconfig.json compile option? I assume something like `"typeRoots": ["./dependencies/nodejs/node_modules/@types"]`

Comment: Answering comments in order. 1. It is lambda and I want to package the code in layers, this why it is more convenient for me to keep node_modules in separate folder. 2. this is autoImport vscode feature, it works when you type something and it offers you to create import of it if it was not defined yet. 3. I specifically mentioned that it is a javascript, not TS.

Comment: "_I specifically mentioned that it is a javascript, not TS_" I know. But VS Code's JS IntelliSense is mostly built off its TS IntelliSense. [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig) supports most of tsconfig.json. Just try it?

Comment: I gave up, and created specific deploy bash script which deploys node_modules and some extra libraries in a separate lambda layer from the root folder... Not the best, but works. It deploys DEV dependencies too, so, kind of overkill for the layer. But still works
When I have more time, will try jsconfig.json. thank you!!